# Changing the context of the function in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm learning how to change the context of the function in Javascript from [this slide](https://johnresig.com/apps/learn/#25). Here the example given is perfectly understandable:

```
var object = {}; 
function fn(){ 
  return this; 
} 
console.log( fn() == this) //true
console.log( fn.call(object) == object); //true
```

But when I try this in Node JS, the result is somewhat different. First statement results in `false` and second equality is working as expected. So is there any difference in Global scope of Node JS and browser?

I know that browser has Global scope named `window`, but what about Node JS? What is the difference between those scopes which leads to the above different behaviours?

Comment: `fn() == this` is evaluating to `true` for me in Node 8.9.3 (note, good to prefer strict equality to sloppy equality)

Comment: @CertainPerformance See this: http://tpcg.io/EJZeya. This is giving same result as my local Node JS. But in browser, both statements evaluates to `true`. My Node Version in 8.11.2

Comment: Ah, I was typing into the REPL directly, rather than running a `.js`, that must be the reason for the difference.

Comment: You should always use strict mode and expect `fn() == undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any difference in Global scope of Node JS and browser?

The difference is that the script isn't evaluated in global scope in Node, it's evaluated in module scope where `this` isn't global variable when it's evaluated directly.

In browser, it is `this === window`. In Node.js, it is `this === module.exports`.

If `fn` was an arrow, it would be `this === module.exports` in Node.js there. But since it's regular function, it's evaluated in global scope when called like `fn()`.

Comment: Then the `this` returned from function `fn` also should be `module.exports` and so 1st statement should evaluate to `true`

Comment: That's what *evaluated directly* refers to. Since `fn` isn't an arrow, it doesn't get `this` from enclosing context (module scope) and is evaluated in global scope. It's same as `eval('this')===module.exports` and `(0, eval)('this')===global`.

Comment: Oh! When I changed it to arrow function, the first returned `true` and second returned `false`! There is too much I don't know about the arrow vs regular functions in JS.

Comment: Arrow functions always get lexical `this`, they ignore a context that is passed with `call`, `apply` or `bind` to them. Consider checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: That is great! I learned many thing today. Thanks.

Comment: @estus "*`fn()` is evaluated in global scope*" - actually, `fn` is called with `undefined` for the `this` argument, and only because it is (not an arrow function and) a **sloppy mode** function the value changes to the global object.